# Implementing the cp command using read/write system calls

Tags: c, unix, system-calls, file-handling

I am trying to implement the `cp` command only using read/write system calls.
Here is my code:

```c
/**
 * cp file1 file 2
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int errsv;
    char contents[1024];
    int fd_read, fd_write;
    fd_read = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd_read == -1)
    {
        errsv = errno;
        printf("Error occured: %d\n", errsv);
    }
    read(fd_read, contents, sizeof(contents));
    fd_write = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0744);
    if (fd_write == -1)
    {
        errsv = errno;
        printf("Error occured: %d\n", errsv);
    }
    write(fd_write, contents, sizeof(contents));
    close(fd_read);
    close(fd_write);
    return 0;
}
```

I tested the code using the commands:

```sh
cc test.c 
./a.out file1 file2
```

Here is my file1:

```
dummy text
dummy text
```

After running the code, although `file2` contains the text from `file1`, it also has some gibberish characters. [*not keeping this here.*] 
Why is this so?

Comment: You need to call `read()` and `write()` in a loop to read the entire file.

Comment: How many bytes does `read(fd_read, contents, sizeof(contents));` actually read?  You don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `read()` and `write()` in a loop to copy the entire file. `read()` returns `0` when you reach EOF, or a negative result if there's an error, then you can end the loop.

`read()` returns the number of bytes that were read, which may be less than the size of the buffer. You need to use that number when calling `write()`, otherwise you'll write extra characters to the output file. These will be unitialized characters on the first iteration, and on other iterations they'll be left over characters from previous iterations.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char contents[1024];
    int fd_read, fd_write;
    fd_read = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

    if (fd_read == -1)
    {
        perror("open input file");
        exit(1);
    }
    fd_write = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0744);
    if (fd_write == -1)
    {
        perror("open output file");
        exit(1)
    }

    int n_read;
    while ((n_read = read(fd_read, contents, sizeof(contents))) > 0) {
        write(fd_write, contents, n_read);
    }

    close(fd_read);
    close(fd_write);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

write(fd_write, contents, strlen(contents));
Strlen returns the filled entries number but sizeof returns the buffer size which is 1024

Comment: *Strlen returns the filled entries number* And what if the first byte in the file is a binary zero?

Comment: `read()` doesn't add a null terminator, you can't use `strlen()`. This also won't work for binary files.

Comment: there is a lot of functions don't add a null terminator ,so collection table that collect them ?